# How to concatenate IIR filter (Butterworth) with a Matlab function and evaluate the integral

Tags: matlab, filters, signal-analysis, lowpass-filter, infinite-impulse-response

I have a function of $j\Omega$ and $v$ (velocity), i.e.:

$$A(j\Omega,v)=\frac{(j\Omega)^2}{p + \frac{j\Omega}{v}}$$

where $p$ is the pole.

I want know how $A(j\Omega,v)$ modify its behavior, when I insert another cascade filter $F(j\Omega)$.

In this case I would like study the power of this system via Parseval's theorem:

$$P(v) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \big|A(j \Omega,v) F(j\Omega)\big|^2 \text{d} \Omega$$

Until yesterday, I have used always the same $F(j\Omega)$, so the Matlab code was long, but simple:

```
acc = @(w,v) ...
    abs( ...
    ((1i.*w).^2).* ...
    (1./(.1+1i.*w./v)) .*...
          ((0.0612.*(1i.*w)+1)./ ...
          (3.375e-06.*(1i.*w).^4+0.0001057.*(1i.*w).^3+0.0167.* ...
          (1i.*w).^2+0.0612.*(1i.*w)+1)) ...
    ).^2;


q = zeros(v_min, v_max);

for v = v_min:v_max;
    q(v) = integral(@(w)acc(w,v), 0, Inf)./pi;
end
```

Where the second part of `acc` is the filter.

This code works and everything is OK.

Now, I do not want put that filter, but several kind of IIR Butterworth low-pass filters.

1. A series, with $F_c = constant$, but with order `N = 1:10`.
2. A second series, with $N = constant$, and `Fc = [1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128]`Hz.

I know that the code for generate these filters is:

```
h  = fdesign.lowpass('N,F3dB', N, Fc, Fs);
Hd = design(h, 'butter');
```

but **my questions is**: how concatenate this filter with a Matlab function, i.e.:

```
A = @(w,v)(((1i.*w).^2).*(1./(.1+1i.*w./v)));
```

for evaluate the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `fdesign` and `design` are for digital filters. Use `butter` instead to obtain the filter coefficients of an analog butterworth filter. Then use the function `freqs` to evaluate the (Laplacian) transfer function of that filter at given frequencies.

To use `integral` I would first create a function that calculates the transfer function of the concatenation of filters A and B. For example:

```
function H = filter_cascade(w, v)
    % transfer function of A
    H_A = ((1i.*w).^2)./(.1+1i.*w./v);

    % the other transfer function
    [b,a] = butter(3, 0.3);
    H_B = freqs(b, a, w);

    % The transfer function of the cascade of A and B
    H = H_A .* H_B;

    % Return the magnitude square of the transfer function
    H = H.*conj(H);
end
```

Then pass a handle to this function to `integral` like this:

```
v = 0.1;
q = integral(@(w)filter_cascade(w,v), 0, 1)./pi;
```

Note that I have changed the upper limit of the integral to one.

Comment: +1 @Deve OK, you are showing me the right way. With `butter` I obtain numerator and denominator of filter transfer function, the parameters that I need. But now, I must to transform this values in a Matlab function, i.e., `F = @(w,v)(A(w,v).*B(w))` where `B(w)` is the Butterworth filter. But I'm still haven't found what I'm looking for: a way for concatenating this two elements and use the result in `integral`.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni I have updated my answer

Comment: I owe you a favor!